# C# Task.Result is Null

Tags: c#, task

I have following method which will eventually return some `Task<IList<DataModel>>` but for now just returns `null`.  I want to load result of this list to ObservableCollection in my ViewModel which is then displayed in a ListView.

But for now, I just want to return null and check that that is handled properly, so my ListView should show nothing in it as a result.  I simmulate that by this code:

```
public async Task<IList<DatatModel>> GetData(string id)
{
    return await Task.FromResult<IList<DataModel>>(null);
}
```

I call the code above and will loop through result of my Task and load it all in my ObservableCollection like so:

```
public void Initialize()
{
    foreach (var data in GetData(Id).Result)
    {
        MyObservableCollection.Add(data);
    }
}
```

However, my app just freezes.  I think that above call to GetData(id).Result is problem because Result is null.  How do I loop through this data and load it into my ObservableCollection if some data exist, or simply dont load anything if there is no data returned?

Comment: what do you mean by freeze? If you call foreach on a null object, I believe that will throw an exception

Comment: "However, my app just freezes" Nope, it doesn't. Or, if your code is actually this, it wouldn't. It'd throw a NRE. What's happening here is unclear. Have you debugged it? Is other code catching and doing something else? Throw your example into a console application and see what happens.

Comment: @Will yes it is NRE, you are right.  So, how to check for null on an Result to not use it if it is null?

Comment: Lots of ways. First thing you need to do is stop using .Result on a task. If you must access a Task without using the async/await pattern, use .ContinueWith. Next, check the result and don't iterate over it if it's null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of returning `null`, return an empty `List<DataModel>`.  That way, your `Result` property will always be populated.  So, your GetData method would become:

```
public async Task<IList<DatatModel>> GetData(string id)
{
    return await Task.FromResult<IList<DataModel>>(new List<DataModel>());
}
```

Comment: The point of the question is how to properly handle a null result.  Avoiding a null result doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Also, you could remove the async/await from the function, both are redundant in this case.